# The set of distinct functions that map $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0\}$ has cardinality 1.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This function is only $f(n) = 0$ right?

Does the wording 'distinct' mean that $f(n) = 0$ and $f(n) = n - n$ are equivalent functions?

Comment: Yes.  And, whoever made up this homework question was likely asleep at the time.

Comment: This was an exam problem. It was like this because as soon as you make it $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0, 1\}$, it becomes uncountable.

Comment: Similarly, your statement is true if you only consider total functions. If you consider partial functions then it's uncountable even for $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0\}$.

Comment: A partial function is not a function. A function that is said to map $\mathbb{N}$ to something must be defined for all values of $\mathbb{N}$. And if it is defined, then it must be set to 0 since that is the only value that exists.

Answer (score 2):

When we say "the / a set of", the notion of "distinct" is usually implicitly assumed, because sets can't contain multiples of an element. Or rather, they can, but conventional set theory has no way of probing whether multiples exist (including when asking about cardinality). So we may as well say that sets can't contain more than one of the same element.

$f(n) = 0$ and $f(n) = n-n$ aren't just equivalent. They are *equal*. They are *the same function*, written in two different ways. So they are both included in this set.

Comment: So the set has only 1 element?

Comment: @MiteshKumar Yup. There is exactly one such function, and that's the one function that is in the set.